# Escaping delimiting character in univocity csv parser

Tags: java, csv, univocity

I have a scenario where one of the rows in the data has the delimiting character in the content.

```
5 |0St"|"ring |field[1]
```

Should always pass - quoted field separator

where the delimiting character is | and it is also present in one of the columns as shown above.

My configuration is as below:

```
quoteChar = "
quoteEscapeChar = \\
```

But when I try to parse the row, it is splitting the column into two separate columns ("0St" and "ring") and failing.

If the put quote around the entire columns as shown below, it works fine.

```
5 |"0St|ring" |field[1]
```

Should always pass - quoted field separator

Is there any setting to specify delimiter escaping character?

I'm using univocity 2.5.9

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Quoting only works on the entire field: `5 |"0St|ring"|field[1]`; maybe `\\|` works.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Tried \\|, didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Author of the library here. I believe I already explained the problem in the [ticket](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/issues/244) you opened, but let me try again:

**Basically that's *NOT* how the CSV format works.**

If you have a field delimiter in your value (i.e. you have a `|` between `0St` and `ring`), your entire value MUST be quoted, i.e. you MUST have your value written as `"0St|ring"` instead of `0St"|"ring`.

Any CSV parser will read `0St"|"ring` into `0St"` then try to process what's after the `|` as another value. There is just nothing else you can do other than writing the entire value within quotes.

The ONLY way to get `0St"|"ring` to be parsed into a single value (I assume you want to get `0St|ring` as a result) is to write your own parsing code to process your data this way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Jeronimo. I had posted the stackoverflow question and github issue together. But I have understood the use case and we have invalidated 0St"|"ring use case